# Correct way to take apart a function

Tags: c#, function

I have a big object and before I do something with it, I need to check for multiple conditions. I have a large function for this. It is unreadable and I want to take it apart for smaller functions to make my code clearer.

The function is checking the conditions and if something isn't right, it stops and returns the problem(which belongs to an `enum` type).

It looks like this:

```
AnswerEnum CheckEverything(Bigobj o)
{
  // some calculation 
  if (...)
   return AnswerEnum.Error1;

  // some more calculation 
  if (...)
   return AnswerEnum.Error2;

  ... 
  return AnswerEnum.OK;
}
```

Now, I want to take the calculations in smaller functions, and I can do is the following:

```
AnswerEnum CheckEverything(Bigobj o)
    { 
    AnswerEnum ret;
    ret=CheckFirstThing(o);
      if (ret!=AnswerEnum.OK)
       return ret;

    ret=CheckSecondThing(o);
      if (ret!=AnswerEnum.OK)
       return ret;

      ... 
      return AnswerEnum.OK;
    }
```

This solution contains

```
if (ret!=AnswerEnum.OK)
   return ret;
```

multiple times and I don't like it. 
I want to minimize the number of `return` statements and any repeating part of the code. How can I do this in this situation?

Comment: Head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all of your check functions have the same signature (which seems to be the case in the code you posted), then all you have to do is create a list of delegates like this:

```
List<Func<Bigobj, AnswerEnum>> list;
```

then you add all your check methods in it during your class initialization:

```
list.Add(CheckFirstThing);
list.Add(CheckSecondThing);
```

and in the end, to check everything:

```
AnswerEnum ret;

foreach(Func<Bigobj, AnswerEnum> f in list)
{
    ret = f(o);
    if (ret != AnswerEnum.Ok) return ret;
}
return AnswerEnum.Ok;
```

Comment: I would go with this solution, nice.

Comment: There's no real reason to define `ret` outside of the loop here.  It should probably be scoped inside of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Define a new method:

```
private AnswerEnum ConditionalCheck(AnswerEnum current, 
                                    Func<BigObj, AnswerEnum> func,
                                    BigObj obj)
{
    return current == AnswerEnum.OK ? func(obj) : current;
}
```

Then modify your code to:

```
AnswerEnum CheckEverything(Bigobj o)
{ 
    var ret = AnswerEnum.OK;
    ret = ConditionalCheck(ret, CheckFirstThing, o);
    ret = ConditionalCheck(ret, CheckSDecondThing, o);
    return ret;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really wanted to reduce down the size of the method, I'd change it to:

```
AnswerEnum CheckEverything(List<Func<BigObj, AnswerEnum> funcs, Bigobj o)
{
    foreach (var func in funcs)
    {
        var result = func(o);
        if (result != AnswerEnum.OK) { return result; }
    }
    return AnswerEnum.OK;
}
```

This way you get to inject the set of checks, so make it easier to read, test and maintain. In addition, checking aborts as soon as something fails, making it faster too.

Comment: Thank You for the answer! It is clear and readable, but I dont like one thing: after finding a problem I don't want to call the other functions, even if they won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it is nicer to use `Delegate Dictionary Design Pattern` (http://wilbloodworth.com/delegate-dictionary-pattern/) when many checkings are to be performed:

```
AnswerEnum CheckEverything(Bigobj o)
{ 
   List<Func<AnswerEnum>> checkings = new List<Func<AnswerEnum>>
   {
     (obj)=>{return CheckFirstThing(obj);},
     (obj)=>{return CheckSecondThing(obj);}
   };

   foreach(var chk in checkings)
   {
      AnswerEnum answer;
      if((answer= chk(o))!=AnswerEnum.OK)
            return answer;
   }
   return AnswerEnum.OK;
}
```